# How to run a virtual desktop and access it using Google Cloud Free Tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need a virtual desktop to access chrome on the go via the Chrome Remote Desktop app on IOS. 
The virtual desktop should be the usual GUI where I can open / install programs like a normal PC. 
I know Windows is not free hence I am stuck with linux.

I created account and I know I need to create an instance.
What instance? How to get GUI? How to setup and access using Chrome Remote Desktop? Etc
Totally clueless.

**What I Did:**

1) I installed a Ubantu instance with a disk space of ***30G***.

2) I went into the shell and tried to run commands for installing a standard ***GUI***.

> **sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop**

3) Immediately received errors of missing dependencies.

Comment: Done !  Sorry if I came across as not trying. Actually I spent a few hours with no luck :(

Comment: You could include what are the steps that you have done so far, what is the result that you are getting, what are the errors that you are getting, etc

Comment: Done .. this this better? I am not sure if I am even doing the right thing and I could not find any answers anyway. Hopefully someone can kindly guide me.

Comment: Try executing `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` then execute `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.